# The most efficient way to calculate numbero of unique values in vector

Tags: r

Is there better way to compute this instead of:

```
length(unique(vector))
```

let's assume that we donno what class is the vector.

Comment: @Cath, they are not asking to do this by group as far as I can see

Comment: @docendodiscimus indeed but you can consider you have only one group and considering the target Q and the answers, I found it close enough (but looking for Q&A to add to the target)

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
library(data.table)
vector <- c(1,2,2,2,3)
uniqueN(vector)
```

Comment: I have found uniqueN to be 3 times slower: data(iris)

x <- rep(unlist(iris),100000)

start <- Sys.time()
length(unique(x))
stop <- Sys.time()
stop - start



start <- Sys.time()
uniqueN(x)
stop <- Sys.time()
stop - start